# How to use BRE or ERE regex to match a pattern which does not have a specific string

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How to use a `posix BRE` or a `posix ERE` regex to match a line that doesn't contain `834` at any place in string?

I want to find `grep '!<pattern>' file` which will be equal to `grep -v '<pattern>' file`.

It is theoretical question on regex, that's why I don't want to use `-v` flag.

I figured out how to list lines, that doesn't contain one character: `^[^8]*$`, for my case I also tried `^$|^.$|^..$|^([^8]..|.[^3].|..[^4])*$`, but that's not working as expected.

Comment: `^([^8]*(8([^38]|3[^48])*)*)*$`

Comment: @mikeserv, not working either :(

Comment: yeah. think i stuck in one too many asterisks. the `(8(...)*)*` will match 8 then fall back to the `[^8]*` when one of the `[^3]|3[^4]` stuff matches. you have to something very like that - but expanded for all possibilities. regex is math - its why `*` 0 is a *place-holder*. negation is perfectly valid regex - you should not try to avoid doing it.

Comment: @mikeserv, Anyway, why my pattern is not working? Shouldn't it check each character from beginning of line to be not a part of 834?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^([^8]*(8([^38]|3[^4])+)*)+$` pattern should do the trick, thanks to mikeserv, who pointed it out to me.